# Can the Google Maps GeoJSON Utility use properties set via geojson.io?

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson

Can the Google Maps GeoJSON Utility use properties set via geojson.io? Such as `marker-color`, `marker-size`, `marker-icon` and so on. Or, is there any extra processing needed because geojson.io uses mapbox or something?